# Finding Pagerank in google

Tags: php, algorithm, pagerank

I would like to know the algorithm to find out the page rank in google search.

Currently I am using php and curl method.

starting from 0 - until found or time limit i submit it to google with different start index.

I would like to know if there is another way or not?

Comment: You may want to read this: http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/5535/Why-Google-Page-Rank-is-Now-Irrelevant.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Google no longer uses the PageRank algorithm to rank search results. They may still generate a number, but it's largely irrelevant. A better means of judging the site would be to use WooRank or something similar. The PageRank value is literally useless.

Hope this puts you on the right path.